Is philosophy of declining influence, effectively dead or irrelevant in modern times? If so, why?
Throughout history, philosophy has played a significant role in shaping societies, morality, and intellectual debates. For example, during the Golden Age of Islam in the Abbasid Caliphate, philosophers were deeply involved in discussions that influenced both religion and science. Medieval times also saw intense debates between philosophers and religious thinkers over key moral and existential issues. Many early scientists, such as Descartes were also philosophers.
However, today, philosophy seems to be viewed by some as dead or irrelevant. Despite encountering complex moral dilemmas—whether in the news or through everyday life—many people don't turn to philosophy for guidance anymore. Philosophical discourse, especially on moral issues, seems to have less influence in shaping modern thought or resolving ethical problems.
I believe we still need philosophy to play a key role in shaping the morality of people. However, I think philosophy should focus on morality and ethics rather than trying to dominate scientific fields. Historically, some philosophers have attempted to interpret the world through their idealized visions, but we now know that this often leads to incorrect conclusions, especially in the realm of science. So while we may not need philosophy to explain the physical world, we still need it to help navigate moral complexities.
Why isn't philosophy flourishing in these areas, especially in guiding modern moral discourse? Or am I mistaken in thinking that it's not flourishing? Even if philosophy is still strong in academia, why does it seem to have less impact on shaping public thought and morality compared to the past?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

What makes you think that philosophy could achieve more correct results in ethics than it can in the sciences?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica it is the best option rn.

The hyperfocus on morality is perhaps a mistake here. idk if this means i'm becoming a crackpot but i'm finding philosophy increasingly relevant when doing math. For certain harder problems/vaguer problems (divergent series comes to mind) it is extremely important to set up a philosophical framework before attempting to do any kind of math. I understand I am late to the party and Physicists have been dealing with this kind of thing since at least mid 1900s as QFT became more mainstream. I suspect philosophy is here to stay and will get more relevant as time goes on.

To be explicit there isn't really any rigorous mathematical content when i say a sentence like "the average value of a function is the best single number to represent the function" and yet it is ideas like these that give rise to divergent regularization that seems to work well in math and can even be experimentally verified in physics. This "pseudo-math" lives slightly outside math in its lack of rigor and so I would say is properly philosophy. This flavor of philosophy is I think going to become more common as the arts and sciences develop.


You start your post with claiming a fact - “Today philosophy is dead
or irrelevant” - and then ask for the cause of the claimed fact.
Hence one has to investigate first whether your claim is true. And
if your claim turns out to be true one can ask for the cause of the
fact.

In former times there was no science at all with its reliable method
of observation, theoretical explanation and testing the result. At
least the final check of the predictions of the theory was impossible.
In early times there were only two methods of explanations for the
phenomena around us: Religion and philosophy.

While the first method often works with anthropomorphic models, the
method of philosophy operates with rational argumentation on the
basis of general principles. But these principles often generalize
from every-day experience, like e.g., ex nihilo nihil fit or the
principle of sufficent reason.
The history of science has shown that this philosophical method cannot access either the microcosmos or the macrocosmos. The philosophical method did not provide reliable results in these domains. As a consequence
philosophy of nature has lost the rivalry with science.

Only in the domain, which is not descriptive like science, but
normative like ethics philosophy has maintained its position.
Therefore, today philosophy is not dead, but its position is strongly
restricted by science.


Aside: I expect some severe objections from other participants of this philosophical blog.

Even though natural philosophy has been outdone by her child, science, we can STILL add philosophy of the natural sciences themselves, like philosophy of biology.  And philosophy of the fields in humanities where science doesn't have a claim, such as philosophy of literature, philosophy of art, philosophy of religion, philosophy of history, philosophy of music, etc.   Or even philosophy of happiness !

Closer of Truth has an entire Season 23 on Philosophy of Biology.

@GratefulDisciple IMO progress is made today by the primary sciences not by the  corresponding secondary philosophy of science. And concerning humanities we have study of literature, study of religions, musicology, and art itself, history itself. - I don't know what philosophy of happiness is.

"In early times there were only two methods of explanations for the phenomena around us: Religion and philosophy" Consider softening that to "two main methods". There were others. Reading signs and omens was neither one. Superstition was neither one. Magic was neither one.

I consider science to be a philosophy.  A philosophy of nature, even.

If you get to the weird parts of science and math such as "divergent series" you can start to see something resembling philosophy occur. In particular "a sum is a sequence, a sequence is a function, the average value of a function is the best single numerical representative of  a function". That last line is NOT mathematical, its an opinion and yet it forms the foundation of how we evaluate things from $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n = \frac{1}{2}$ to more complex ideas like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n = -\frac{1}{12}$. There is some "proto-math" happening here that is properly philosophy.

Physics, Computer Science, Statistics are rich with examples of this too I believe.

@candied_orange religion can be classified under superstition (at the very least, even for those who believe, it is certainly common to classify other people's religion as a superstition), and magic can absolutely be classified as a religion (especially more formalized systems like modern ceremonial magic). All of these things you mention (superstition, reading signs, magic) were basically extensions of their practitioner's religions.

@terdon If I take enough drugs I can classify a sound as tasting funny. My point is claiming that every explanation for phenomena used to be religion or philosophy paints an inaccurate picture of our past. For example, tradition existed and exists well outside religion. Yes religions try to make it part of themselves. Doesn't make Sunday dinner with Grandma a religious thing. When you stretch a concept to extremes it stops meaning anything.

@JoWehler See Philosophy of happiness. Looks like philosophy's relevance is tightly connected to how we define it. Maybe I'm outdated or naïve or ignorant, but I would define "philosophy" as "thinking about  in a human way, for contemplation of its meaning, purpose, utility, origin" so this consideration is separate from investigating that  in itself and bigger than the morality of it. If this dimension is deemed not worthwhile, I take it as a sign that the utilitarian has taken over the humanistic.

@GratefulDisciple I understand: Philosophy of happiness, as far as eudiamonia is meant, is discussed in Aristotle's Nicomachean Ethics. In modern ethics the question "How to live a good life?" has indeed retreated into the background.

@SidharthGhoshal Neither of those equalities is correct. Ramanujan summation is not the evaluation of a divergent series and no rigorous mathematician would claim it was, nor that it's "the best single numerical representative of a function" (and a sequence isn't a function). It's just a convenient replacement for traditional summation in certain specific scenarios (and an annoying, clickbait-y thumbnail from Numberphile).

@SidharthGhoshal If you want more information on it, both answers on this Math.SE question are helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719566/how-does-it-equal-1-12

@Idran if-by-equality-you-mean-convergence then of course they aren’t correct. If you stretch the definition of equality to mean “$O(1)$ convergence” then those identities are literally correct. See my answer here which generalizes techniques here.

Moreover these identities organically appear elsewhere in math AND physics (the latter of which can be experimentally verified which is extremely significant as it means “we aren’t merely symbol shuffling. Nature appears to have an opinion these divergent sums are safe to take at face value). See the derivation here , Re: $-\frac{1}{12}$ it’s a myth that this can only be derived by the Riemann Zeta function see my answer here

Enlightenment philosophy had tremendous impact on the world -- creating the Scientific revolution, the industrial revolution, and the ending of aristocracy as the world's dominant societal model.
Post enlightenment politics is all based on moral philosophic thinking:

Liberalism: Society is improvable, using the tools of good governance, and the sciences of sociology and psychology and the effective democracy of free market economics to enable all of us democratically to select the greatest good for the greatest number

Conservatism:  humans are fallible and tend toward violence and cheating -- one must have a strong state and social institutions to restrain our worst impulses, and maintaining our historical Darwinianly selected social institutions and norms is the best way to do that

Socialism: pure markets are socially broken because they create oligarchies, to preserve human freedom and opportunity we need to nationalize key industries and devote their profits to the welfare of all -- using the best science of production planning.

Communism: Oligarchs will always capture the state through financial influence, unless the class is liquidated.  The only path to a bright future for humanity is the moral re-education of society by a committed morally motivated party to banish selfishness and greed.


What happened to philosophy in the 20th century was three trends that removed a lot of its influence on culture:

The dominant philosophic movement in the Anglo-American community is analytic philosophy.  Analytics seeks to derive conclusions rationally, using logic, and precise careful definitions and derivations.  Frege and Russell, however, failed when they tried to derive mathematics from logic, and Godel's incompleteness theory showed why.  The Munchausen Trilemma also shows how no derivation will every fully close.  Analytics have remained dominant, but without the ability to derive anything of major import, the movement primarily now works on technical abstract problems, eschewing any significant or global claims.  A representative subject would be Gettier problems: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUttOHifiIAxXDFVkFHRr8FEMQFnoECBMQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fiep.utm.edu%2Fgettier%2F%23%3A~%3Atext%3DOn%2520the%2520face%2520of%2520it%2Cenough%2520for%2520its%2520being%2520knowledge.&usg=AOvVaw04sM0tpuwM4pIrQPEP44p5&opi=89978449 , which would be unlikely to motivate any kind of broad societal movement or influence ...
Continental philosophy did not abandon big issues and was dominated for a time in the early 20th century by Structuralism, which found global commonalities between many aspects of our world, potentially revealing essential truths about our universe, and thinking (example, Joseph Campbell's comparative mythology finding the essence of humanity in the Voyage of the Hero).  But critics of structuralism used the method against itself, showing that the fundamental structure the structuralists were discovering was actually embedded in their methodology!  That we are unable to think without preconceptions, and that preconceptions drive one's conclusions, was a valid conclusion, but it was over-generalized to reject all conclusions in any study as skewed by the motives of the authors by the post-structuralists (now known as post-modernists).  Post modernism is now the dominant Continental movement, but it is hampered in its influence: if one cannot trust justifications, then it is difficult to justify anything philosophically.
Physicalism: The majority of philosophers in both continental and English-American philosophy in the 20th century were physicalists, and this has a detrimental effect on the interest and justification of ethical and moral theorizing.  If everything is physical, then what are ethics, and how can one derive them? Physicalism hampered the moral/ethical focus you advocate for.

Despite these obstacles, one of the more significant intellectual movements of recent decades is primarily philosophical, and it is the rise of Skeptic societies, and the associated New Atheist movement engaging in a primarily moral critique of religion.
So no, philosophy is far from dead or irrelevant, but there are current trends that make it less inclined to pursue relevance.

You can say that philosophy is in decline in our times. But so are many other intellectual fields. In the modern world, you can live your life quite comfortably, without serious literature, serious music, serious thinking.
But the traditional school of thought historically represented by philosophers is a hidden fire that has to be preserved and passed from generation to generation, even if we are currently not aware of its practical purpose.

I'd say in any stage of human society you could have lived and probably many did without any of those. Be wary of our schooling which puts those in the spotlight.

Your claims that philosophy has declined may be linked to a putative divergence in scientific endeavors and the humanities as detailed in The Two Cultures by C.P. Snow. Certainly, up until the 20th century, to be educated was to be knowledgeable about literature and philosophy. For instance, Louis Menand is his The Metaphysical Club outlines a thesis that after the civil war, US intellectual life at the turn of the century was tremendously influenced by Oliver Wendell Holmes, John Dewey, Charles Sanders Pierce, and William James, and these are all men who knew philosophy and contributed to it (law, education, math and logic, and psychology to oversimplify). But by the time WWII had ended, sciences and their influence on society were clearly established.
According to the article on The Two Cultures (whose original essay-form can be found here):

good many times I have been present at gatherings of people who, by the standards of the traditional culture, are thought highly educated and who have with considerable gusto been expressing their incredulity at the illiteracy of scientists. Once or twice I have been provoked and have asked the company how many of them could describe the Second Law of Thermodynamics. The response was cold: it was also negative. Yet I was asking something which is the scientific equivalent of: Have you read a work of Shakespeare's?4 I now believe that if I had asked an even simpler question – such as, What do you mean by mass, or acceleration, which is the scientific equivalent of saying, Can you read? – not more than one in ten of the highly educated would have felt that I was speaking the same language. So the great edifice of modern physics goes up, and the majority of the cleverest people in the western world have about as much insight into it as their neolithic ancestors would have had.

Thus, it's fair to say that specialization and the modern university system have encouraged by necessity gulfs among the various disciplines, and since the logical positivists, natural science has been somewhat indifferent if not hostile to philosophy. Rudolf Carnap's views on Metaphysics (SEP) are views that have been echoed by more than one scientist:

Carnap took entirely for granted (so deeply that he hardly ever bothered to make it explicit) that literature, art, and music shaped people’s values and were closely connected with them. But these were for individuals to negotiate... Objective knowledge was, to him as to the Enlightenment, at the core of this shared framework. Practical (especially political) decisions should be informed ones, arrived at in the light of the best possible knowledge about the available choices and their consequences... Metaphysics was, in his view, a distraction from this program. Metaphysics was a kind of failed art form masquerading as knowledge, so it was both fake art and fake knowledge. Unlike a logical or mathematical proof or the confirmation of a scientific theory, metaphysical proposals are unable to command widespread agreement; even the criteria by which they should be judged are often in dispute.

Thus, there's a perspective that is typical of David Gudeman's response to your question, that philosophy has somehow died, run its course, and evolved into better intellectual activities. He says:

As soon as philosophy does anything seen as practical or valuable, it immediately forks of into its own discipline or practical methodology. As soon as any philosophical movement becomes popular, it becomes a religion or ideology instead of philosophy. In your example of Islam, there is no sharp distinction between academic philosophy and religious scholarship. What is known as philosophy today is basically what is left over after everything influential has been removed.

This, of course, is at best hyperbole, and at worst an ignorance of how active and important philosophical discourse is today. Today, there are those who practice what they call experimental philosophy. Related to that are computational philosophers (SEP) who are very involved in keeping philosophy active along an axis orthogonal to information and computer technology. Also, applied philosophers among whom ethicists are extremely active. Even the Catholic church, who may be the largest organization of theologists take a very active role in practicing philosophy to dispute and defend atheist claims. And arguably, the best scientists in the field are some of the most philosophically sophisticated. The logical positivists were deeply entwined with the work of physicists and while they didn't produce much in the field of physics, they had productive relationship with their fellow physicists.
The social sciences, too, have emerged as philosophers using their voices ever more stridently since the 1970's to advocate antipositivist claims. The philosophical tensions in the post-positivist world are alive and well, and if any claims should be made of philosophy, it is that scientific progress is largely hindered by a lack of philosophical awareness. Here's a recent rant by Sabine Hossenfelder entitled This is why physics is dying (YT) drags out into light certain mathematical physicists who she believes aren't actually doing physics correctly because they refuse to accept they are no longer following the scientific method.
Following Brockman's The Third Culture as a follow-up to Snow's thesis, there are a number of intellectuals today who place primacy on philosophy as a discipline. Certainly, in my own field of computer science, any AI researcher who believes that philosophy of mind and language is irrelevant shouldn't have been granted a PhD (a Doctor of Philosophy, mind you). This third culture was even brought into the web-age with the establishment of Edge.org, a site to devoted to re-enriching the technical details of mathematical logic, language, and the sciences with contemporary metaphysical practice. (Yes, Socrates is important, but so too is the post-Quinean landscape)
Thus, moral discourse about AI and technology has a bastion in the global corporate world, and the major religions have to take philosophy and science on pain of being irrelevant. Anyone who claims that philosophy is essentially nothing more than a left-over debate about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin is woefully uneducated about what philosophy is. Such a person is strong encouraged to read Edward Craig's Philosophy: A Very Short Introduction to get a better sense of what philosophy is and why it is still very much important.

It's impossible to compare the influence of "philosophy" in other times and other cultures to what is called philosophy today. In previous times, philosophy included a large range of topics including science, politics, religion, and advice for living a good life. Today philosophy is a highly restricted pure academic discipline. When philosophy produces any doctrine seen as practical or valuable, that doctrine forks off into its own discipline or practical methodology. As soon as any philosophical movement becomes popular, it becomes a religion or ideology instead of philosophy. What is known as philosophy today is basically what is left over after everything influential has been removed.
Here are some examples of what I'm talking about: Galileo and others who spawned the Scientific Revolution were seen as doing philosophy; his philosophy and that of Descartes, Newton and others led to modern physics. The philosophies of Dalton, Lavoisier, and Boyle led to modern chemistry. Natural history was a branch of philosophy that studied nature. It eventually developed over time into modern biology, geology, oceanography, paleontology and all the technologies using electricity and magnetism. Charles Darwin was seen as part philosopher when he introduced the theory of evolution. Today all of that work is considered science rather than philosophy.
Martin Luther was largely doing philosophy when he started the Protestant Reformation. In fact large numbers of Christian sects, heresies, and doctrines started as philosophical musing. Arguably, Jesus himself and John the Baptist were itinerate philosophers who created one of the world's great religions. Buddhism and Taoism also both seem to have started as philosophy. Today, all of that thought is considered religion rather than philosophy.
The American Revolution and the French Revolution were sparked by Enlightenment philosophy and those philosophies developed into laws, political ideologies and even international law. Karl Marx was doing philosophy when he wrote some of the most influential and deadly books in history, inspiring Fascism, Nazism, and all of the communist revolutions in the 20th century. Today all of those theories and doctrines are considered political theory or ideology rather than philosophy.
What is considered philosophy today has all of those influential doctrines and many others excluded from it, so naturally what is left seems a lot less influential.

I would have to disagree completely, in what philosophy has become a religion at any point in time? give some examples. Also, philosophy is not a "pure academic discipline" People may simply learn about philosophy for fun, or pursue a degree in it, but that does not mean in any sense it is purely academic. many still do look towards philosophy to find guidance for their life questions; some may even conform to a certain philosophy as a basis to live their life.

@Kaden-P, I've added examples in the answer. And there aren't any philosophers who give guidance on how to live life any more. Anyone who does that is not considered a genuine philosopher these days.

I am sorry but I fail to see examples where philosophy directly turned into religion, you mentioned Buddhism and Taoism but didn't elaborate. As far as I can tell, Religion is at best influenced by philosophy but philosophy has never become a religion. "Martin Luther was doing philosophy"?

Also, I would like to say that you should avoid the opinion, "Anyone who does is not considered a genuine philosopher these days." As well as that there doesn't have to be philosophers who directly give life advice "These days" modern stoics are very much a thing, I would consider myself one.

@Kaden-P, you are starting with a wrong assumption: that there was a clear demarcation between philosophy and religion, and that a doctrine on one side swapped to the other. Before the nineteenth century, there was never that strong a demarcation between the two, and in much of the world there still isn't. The examples I mentioned were all recognized as doing something more philosophical than religious when they started, and then the doctrines evolved into something considered mostly religion.

@Kaden-P, modern stoics are not considered philosophers; they are considered advocates of an ideology.

I'm squinting really hard to try to read this as some kind of an endorsement of religion so that I can understand the anonymous downvotes, but I just can't see it.

I would suggest a small change: [As soon as any philosophical movement becomes popular, it becomes a religion or ideology] - or a practical methodology. (Plus an example or two if you like.) ...Also I think you're giving Galileo way too much credit.

@gs, I'm surprised at your comment about Galileo. He invented modern dynamics and telescopic astronomy, made major contributions to statics, strength of materials, and fluid dynamics, and popularized the heliocentric theory. All of the other main figures in the Scientific Revolution other than the astronomers and William Gilbert were directly influenced by his work.

This is the answer I would have given; philosophy's not conquered, it's just divided. A couple of examples of modern forking-off for stuff that matters that I've seen in big business are "HR ethics"/"equity & inclusion" (where the letter of the law is applied to a company's philosophical beliefs), and "responsible AI"/"AI ethics" (one of the more interesting and divisive areas of modern philosophy).

@DavidGudeman I'm not saying that Galileo didn't make significant contributions, I'm saying that he was an important early figure contributing to (and informed by, formally educated in, and professionally employed specifically to perpetuate) an intellectual movement that had been in full swing for decades by the time he contributed anything to it, not the creator of that movement. To me the claim and defense reads like if I were to claim that Calvin started the Protestant revolution, and defended it with the importance of Institutes on theologians after the 1540s.

Peter Singer is a Professor of Bioethics at Princeton. Richard Rorty was professor of comparative literature at Stanford. Bertrand Russell worked as deeply on mathematical theory as philosophy, & was extemely politically involved & outspoken. Modern philosophers of significance have been very interdisciplinary, in their lives & work. You seem to be talking about the academic study of philosophy, though. Also, the Paris Commune predated Marx's work, as did the Diggers - he was an important theorist of it, but he didn't 'start Communism'.

@CriglCragl, I can't figure out the point of your comments about Singer, Rorty, and Russel. As to Marx, "communism" as used normally doesn't refer to living in communes; it refers to a theory of history and related revolutionary theory.

It is flourishing, in that area, as well as others. Look up Peter Singer, his work on animal rights, meducal ethics, and charitable giving for instance.
But also look at Nick Bostrom's work on Artificial General Intelligence, where he develops the idea of 'mind-crimes' to get at the harms we could do to digital minds unlike our own, and how that could lead us to conflict or other kinds of misalignment with such future minds. This is about ethics, and also consciousness, and computation. Our challenges don't fall into neat silos.
Some other roles for philosophy are demarcation between fields (inc defining philosophy), investigating words (eg assumptions involved and edge cases), dealing with rhetoric and 'pursuasion without regard to truth', wisdom self-knowledge and the nature of a meaningful or good life, how to understand society and social change in relation to how we should do politics, and many other areas.
I think you are romanticising the past, and until the last century or so many people weren't even literate, so the records we have were much more only from a narrow elite, that largely still held to a classical education that included Latin and Greek, plus texts in those languages. In the modern era people largely don't see that as a good use of time. But Philosophy majors are smarter than others — and tend to make more money.
More on the role of philosophy:
(Why) is this negative outlook on the concept of philosophy misguided?

What's Bostrom up to since this? https://www.oxfordstudent.com/2024/04/20/oxford-shuts-down-elon-musk-funded-future-of-humanity-institute/

@JimmyJames: He published a book in March, '
Deep Utopia: Life and Meaning in a Solved World'. And is now Principal Researcher at the Macrostrategy Research Initiative, an organisation that was incorporated last August but seems to not have it's own website, & appears to be a successor to the Future of Humanity Institute. His research papers are on his personal website: https://nickbostrom.com/

Philosophy may seem dead in modern times because we have answers for things essential to progress in society and the rest can be seen as irrelevant.
What I mean by this is that the Greeks and Romans used philosophy to ask questions about their universe that weren't answered by the tales of their gods.
In modern times we have religion and something that, for the most part, the Greeks and Romans did not; Science.
Most of our questions have an explanation thanks to science, and anything existential is answered by religion. The average person doesn't care to ask philosophical questions.
As an example, the Founding Fathers had influence when creating the United States from the Greek and Roman governments.
The way ancient civilizations (functional intelligent ones) lasted was by creating governments that came from asking philosophical questions or appointing rulers through gods.
And it goes deeper than that, words we use every day are influenced by Greek and Latin, So much of what we know is influenced by their culture. I think that now we have answers to most we need as a society there is no purpose for the average person to go any further.
The Greeks and Romans asked the question when they didn't have the answers, we no longer need to ask such questions to understand the world around us. Most philosophical questions don't have an actual answer, it will be different to everyone you ask and that isn't helpful in modern times.
We have science and religion to explain things, Therefore we don't need to use philosophy to answer our questions anymore. The ones important to society at least. Sure philosophy is fun, But the reason it is irrelevant is because we can go without using it.

The OP assumes that there was once upon a time when philosophy and philosophers were more influential than they are today. I wonder when that was. Was it when the Athenians poisoned Socrates? When Plato dreamed of a fascist state? When the Church burnt Giordano Bruno? Or perhaps closer to us, when Hegel called Napoleon the "spirit of the world" and licked the boots of the Prussian state? When Nietzsche glorified the übermench, when Marx criticized liberal democracy, when Heiddeger loved Hitler, when Sartres defended the Soviets?
The interplay between politics and philosophy has historically been treacherous. Maybe it's a good thing if our statemen don't pay attention to philosophers anymore. But do they? Don't our leaders believe in something?
Yes, they do believe in capitalism (even though it's messing up the climate) and science and technology, I think, inasmuch as they are sources of power. One can add to that, at least in the case of Europe and the US and such, some vague references to "democracy" and "culture", whatever that means in those post-truth times when folks can and will believe anything they see on YouTube.
In this depressing, minimalist spiritual environment, many people are IMO thirsty for meaning, and I want to think that philosophy is making a timid come-back.
A few years ago I noticed advertisement in the subway for philosophical courses, sold as personal development of course, but with a spiritual vibe. I found it interesting that there was apparently a market... Today, there are many philosophical cafés out there where people congregate to exchange their deepest questions, and websites and forums such as this one, and resources like the SEP. Since COVID and the confinement, "the community" has only got bigger.
Philosophers get invited in talkshows nowadays, and they too have YouTube channels.
Sophia not dead.

Philosophy is very much alive and well and highly relevant in the Scientific field.
I was uncertain about this "some years ago". Listening to overviews by people expert in the field rapidly made it entirely clear that what are often seen as "solid scientific foundations" are in fact very often just as founded on impressions, interpretations, perspectives and the like. These may come about through some mix of historical happenstance, personal preferences and prejudices, "received-truth" positions by foundations and even whole societies. And more :-) .
Thinking that philosophy has no relevance in the field of modern scientific endeavour is a reasonable indication of its need :-).
Wikipedia - Philosophy of Science
Reasonably good.

Philosophy of science is the branch of philosophy concerned with the foundations, methods, and implications of science. Amongst its central questions are the difference between science and non-science, the reliability of scientific theories, and the ultimate purpose and meaning of science as a human endeavour. Philosophy of science focuses on metaphysical, epistemic and semantic aspects of scientific practice, and overlaps with metaphysics, ontology, logic, and epistemology, for example, when it explores the relationship between science and the concept of truth. Philosophy of science is both a theoretical and empirical discipline, relying on philosophical theorising as well as meta-studies of scientific practice. Ethical issues such as bioethics and scientific misconduct are often considered ethics or science studies rather than the philosophy of science. ... "

Berkley

"In this website, we use a practical checklist to get a basic picture of what ​​science is and a flexible flowchart to depict how science works. For most everyday purposes, this gives us a fairly complete picture of what science is and is not. However, there is an entire field of rigorous academic study that deals specifically with what science is, how it works, and the logic through which we build scientific knowledge. This branch of philosophy is handily called the philosophy of science. Many of the ideas that we present in this website are a rough synthesis of some new and some old ideas from the philosophy of science.
Despite its straightforward name, the field is complex and remains an area of current inquiry. Philosophers of science actively study such questions as:
What is a ​​law of nature? Are there any in non-physical sciences like biology and psychology?
What kind of ​​data can be used to distinguish between real causes and accidental regularities?
How much ​​evidence and what kinds of evidence do we need before we accept ​​hypotheses?
Why do scientists continue to rely on ​​models and ​​theories which they know are at least partially inaccurate (like Newton’s physics)? ... "


Google search - legion
Springer
10 links
University of Otago - Phil225
A look at the topic list under "paper structure" gives a useful ide of how deep this subject can be.
What is science? How does it differ from other disciplines? Do its methods yield a superior type of knowledge? Why do scientists perform experiments and what can those experiments show?

"The philosophy of science focuses on philosophical issues regarding scientific reasoning, methods and concepts. The topics in this paper include: What makes something a science? How are scientific theories generated? Can theories be proven? What makes a good scientific explanation? How should we understand and evaluate scientific models? What drives theory change in science? ..."

Wikipedia - History and philosophy of science
With video
Short essay - University of Cincinnati
Reddit

Many comments. Some good material

Science Direct
Various snippets and links.
Useful.

The OP wrote:

... I think philosophy should focus on morality and ethics rather than trying to dominate scientific fields.

While I agree that philosophy should not try to dominate a scientific field, I think it can contribute to an emerging discipline. For example, I am impressed by Andy Clark's clarification of some of the questions in cognitive science. Professor Clark is a cognitive philosopher. Maybe the role of a philosopher is to ask questions, then for the scientists to decide whether they are decidable or not.

+1 Indeed, the luminaries of every scientific endeavor become philosophers by necessity.

I am not sure that there is a strong difference across the ages about how philosophia has been flourishing.
First of all, philosophia is a foundation for science, even if it is not evident at first sight, because it teaches not to blindly trust what seems commonly accepted, but to bring a second view. That is probably the reason why it was necessary to by-pass the various obscurantisms.
It seems to be less required in modern sciences, because the scientific approach is now heavily based on the doubt and any new statement requires reproducible proofs. But we should be aware that wondering whether the quantic mechanics is the physical reality at atomic scale or is just a mathematical tool that gives interesting results is more a philosophical question than a scientific one.
It is of course required for ethical questions because when we ask ourselves an ethical question, it means that some of us agree with one statement and others do not. Religions can hardly help here become their laws are ancient and cannot follow social evolutions. Only the philosophical approach can analyze the individual and social outcomes of an ethical decision.
Now the last question is whether philosophia is less listened nowadays. In fact philosophers have always been few among the global population. But the people able to publish books and have their opinions known were very few too. And kings had not to care about their re-election so they have little interest in their subjects'opinions. That is probably a reason why the wisdom of philosophers looked promising in the era of enlightened despots.
IMHO the major difference is that among all the people that post messages on social networks or other mass media, few care for philosophia. And most of potential readers/receivers do not care more. That does not mean that philosophia is not present, but it is just hidden behind the mass of sex/business/fashion/add_your_own_here noise.
Let us think a moment about the abortion question in US. Do you think that a philosophical study about that can found its place on X, tik-tok or facebook? And do you think that people used to snap judgements (think of Trump positions...) are ready to read such a study? But on the other hand, to you think that the peasants of the 18th century were interested in philosophical questions? And what about the metics and helots of ancient greece?
What I mean is that philosophia is now what is has always been: few people care for abstract questions with concrete outcome, and a few more listen to them. And the vast majority just ignore it. But if you add a political view on those question, you could wonder whether social network and other media owners really wish that their users care for philosophia. The more they do philosophia the less they blindly receive messages... It may be an old man thought, but when the global population is involved, I never forget that the most powerful can easily have an influence on the others, and that humans' herd instinct is to follow the most widely held opinion.
